# Excel - Duplicate values in Pivot Table?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, pivot-table

I am pulling my hair out here, For simplicity sake, here's the problem.

Column A has many IDs, some are duplicated. The Pivot table uses this ID Source sheet, and creates a table......now for some reason it shows duplicate IDS, instead of displaying unique IDS as a whole (like pivot tables should?).

I re-created another Pivot Table, thinking it was an issue with how its setup. The same duplicate IDS show. I thought perhaps, the duplicated IDS, have a space after there numbers, creating duplicates in the Pivot Table. So I ran a =len() on all IDS, there all the same length, no spaces......

I am lost right now as to why this pivot table is display duplicated IDS, when it does for some, and not for other duplicate IDS in the source sheet.

Comment: Any Access to eventual source data coming before Excel? Maybe due to non printable caractères.

Comment: I do have access to the source, its all derived from columns that are labelled data type as "General"

Comment: I was referring not to Excel document but (if that exists) the source from where data come to feed the Excel (copy/paste from where, imported from where and so on)

Comment: Ahh.. I grab the source from a consolidated file in SharePoint. From the SharePoint file, I believe someone extracts the data from SQL and uploads it to SharePoint. So the source is inside of SQL Server, this could prove to be difficult to resolve...

Comment: Can you ask at database owner to create checks, for instance for records containing your ID (query really on 'contains', not equal).?

Answer (score 0):

How many duplicate IDs are showing in your pivot table for one unique value in the ID data set? If its just two, then its possible that some of your IDs in the original data set are stored as text with a leading single quote mark. In this case, setting the entire column as format cells > general wont change them. Furthermore, the LEN test wont include the extra prefixed quote mark...

If there is a green arrow in the top left corner of the cells, select them and convert to number from the drop down...

Comment: For 1 unique value, 2 duplicate values show inside the Pivot Table. The source file that contains this Unique value, has many duplicates (5-20 rows).

i.e. Pivot has ID "123", the filter shows "123", 2 or 3 times......   Source Data - contains "123" but is listed 20 times, so I am unsure of how to approach this, if you had said my LEN test isn't producing the right length of characters. I am at a loss right now unfortunately

Comment: If that's the case, then I strongly believe that some of your ID's in your original data set are being stored as text (prefixed with a single quote mark) as opposed to other formats....

Try sorting your data (A to Z or lowest to highest) by your ID's. Do some values get excluded from the sort order and put at the bottom of your dataset (when they shouldn't do)? This will most likely mean they are numbers being stored as text...